# Google Search API ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api

I am using rails 2.3. My requirement is to get the top 20 links from Google search of a query.

I want to use the  http://rubygems.org/gems/google-api-client gem.

But I am not able to find any proper documentation for doing custom google search with authentication. Can any one point me to an example, from where I can understand how to use the google-api-client gem for custom google search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a look at the API and it doesn't seem to difficult... Just need to define which of [google's api's](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/wiki/SupportedAPIs) you want to use. In your case it would seem you that want to use the [customsearch api.](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest)

So your code should look something like:

```
require 'google/api_client'
my_search_client = Google::APIClient.new
google_search = my_search_client.discovered_api('customsearch')
response = my_search_client.execute(
  google_search.cse.list, 'q' => 'your query'
)
status, headers, body = response
```

For the authentication part you should be able to copy and paste directly from [this page](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/wiki/Documentation). Just use your own values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It helped a lot. I have few more questions,
1. Every time I am trying to use the api, it is asking to set the access_token. Specifically I am getting the following message, "ArgumentError: Missing access token."
2. If I set a dummy access token, then also I am getting no result, instead getting the following message, "Invalid Credentials".
  I have set the "key" and "cx" value. And if I use the same url, generated by the api, in the browser I am getting correct results.
Any Idea?

Comment: It looks like you can just set a dummy access token. Do something like: my_search_client.authorization.access_token = '123'

Comment: Actually, just do: my_search_client.authorization = nil

Comment: Thanks Sean....
Actually my_search_client.authorization = nil worked fine as I don't need to log to use this API.

Answer (score 7):

If anyone stumble on this, this is an updated version of this code:

*Gemfile*

```
gem 'google-api-client', '~> 0.11'
```

*search.rb*

```
require 'google/apis/customsearch_v1'
Search = Google::Apis::CustomsearchV1
search_client = Search::CustomsearchService.new
search_client.key = 'YOUR API KEY'
response = search_client.list_cses('your query', {cx: 'Search Engine ID'})
status, headers, body = response

pp status
pp headers
pp body
```

Hope this helps!